# How can i calculate percentage change of sum of two columns in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` with several columns, I want to sum up two columns with integers and calculate percentage change of the sums. I have tried with `lambda` but I cant seem to find the right code. Please help.

Comment: please provide the dfs you have and the desired results.

Comment: Or even better; an attempt to solve it yourself, up to the point where you really get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'A1':[1,2,3,4],'A2':[1,3,5,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['PctChg'] = (df.A2 - df.A1)/df.A1 * 100
df
     A1  A2      PctChg
 0   1   1    0.000000
 1   2   3   50.000000
 2   3   5   66.666667
 3   4   9  125.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `pct_change`, data from SciGuyMcQ

```
df.sum(1).pct_change()
Out[331]: 
0      NaN
1    1.500
2    0.600
3    0.625
dtype: float64
```